# How do I call the Azure REST API from an interactive PowerShell session

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to be able to call Azure REST API methods from an interactive PowerShell session.  There are instructions on how to do this with a Service Principal [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2017/06/28/using-powershell-as-an-azure-arm-rest-api-client/) but I want to be able to call these methods using my own credentials rather than switching to a different set.  This will make it easier to work out the methods I need to call locally and also to gather information from Azure on an ad hoc basis.

An example of a call I'd like to make that can't be done with existing PowerShell cmdlets is

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/products/{productId}/policies/policy?api-version=2019-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login to Azure with Login-AzureRmAccount or Login-AzAccount and then call an AzureRm or Az cmdlet a bearer token will be obtained by from Azure and stored in your context object.  You can retrieve your context object with Get-AzureRmContext or Get-AzContext and parse the token from that object.

```
    $Context = Get-AzContext
    $Cache = $Context.TokenCache
    $CacheItems = $Cache.ReadItems()
    $Token = ($CacheItems | Where-Object { $_.Resource -eq "https://management.core.windows.net/" })
```

The token will last for an hour, if it expires you'll need to renew it by calling an Azure cmdlet again (though it may be possible to renew it programatically).

This code could be wrapped in a function like

```
function Invoke-AzureRestApi {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Uri
    )

    $Context = Get-AzContext
    $Cache = $Context.TokenCache
    $CacheItems = $Cache.ReadItems()
    $Token = ($CacheItems | Where-Object { $_.Resource -eq "https://management.core.windows.net/" })
    $Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Token.AccessToken)"}

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers

}

# run an Az or AzureRm cmdlet to get a token prior to calling the function
Invoke-AzureRestApi -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/products/{productId}/policies/policy?api-version=2019-01-01

# A simpler example to test the function (though this particular example can be more easily achieved with Get-AzResourceGroup)
Invoke-AzureRestApi -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-08-01
```

UPDATE (31/8/2021):
the token can now be retrieved simply using the Get-AzAccessToken cmdlet

```
function Invoke-AzureRestApi {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Uri
    )
    
    $Token = Get-AzAccessToken
    $Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Token.Token)"}
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, Instead of using the cached token, do you know of a way to initiate the prompt that Login-AzAccount would produce? My intention is not to use Login-AzAccount at all for a scenario where Az modules are unavailable and completely use REST. I tried posting to the oAuth endpoint using Invoke-WebRequest but unfortunately the login form is non-interactive, instead i need a prompt window.

Comment: @Sumesh it sounds like you're trying to create your own authentication flow (as opposed to leveraging the existing PowerShell authentication flow to make debugging scripts locally easier).  You might want to start with the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) or post a new question with more detail about what you've implemented already

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `Get-AzResource` to achieve the same outcome, without the headache of dealing with tokens.

Your particular example call doesnt make a lot of sense, it can be replaced with `Get-AzResourceGroup`

Comment: Good point, I've amended the question and answer to include an example that is more relevant